# Jsoup in Android

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Estou com dificuldade em executar minha aplicação Android com o Jsoup. É um exemplo simples, mas que está a retornar nada.

Classe em Java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView textview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();
        String title = doc.title();
        textview.setText(title);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        textview.setText("aaaa");
    }
}

}
```

Layout activity_main.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

manifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.teste12.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Obs: Também foi inserido no caminho do jsoup.jar.

Segue o Log abaixo:

```
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.study01/com.example.study01.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1131)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:439)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:167)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at com.example.study01.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5058)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
03-09 00:53:39.281: E/AndroidRuntime(8413):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: No Logcat aparece alguma mensagem ou exceção?

Answer (score 1):

Se reparar está a ser lançada um exceção `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, isto acontece porque está a ser realizada uma operação de rede na thread principal. Essa exceção ocorre a partir da API 11.

[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

As operações de rede deverão ser feitas de forma assíncrona, por exemplo com uma [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Deverá fazer algo deste tipo:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        new MyAsyncTask().execute("http://google.com");
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Document> {

        @Override
        protected Document doInBackground(String... params) {
            Document doc = null;
            try{
                doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();

            }catch (Exception e){
                doc = null;
            }

            return doc;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Document result) {
            if (result != null) {
                String title = result.title();
                textview.setText(title);
            } else {
                textview.setText("aaaa");
            }
        }
    }
}
```